# RDCOMClient (Outlook) - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rdcomclient

I'm using the `RDCOMClient` library to create an Outlook email. I want to send a `ggplot` as an image inside the email body (inline), **not** as an attachment.

The only way I see this as possible is adding the plot as an image inside the `HTMLBody` property. I tried 2 different methods to add the image in html.

**1 -** Using the `RMarkdown` library, I created a html page with the plot. This did not work because the image is encoded as a `base64` string, that Outlook does not support.

**2 -** Saving the ggplot to a file and manually creating a simple html such as: `<html><body><img src="**path**/my_plot.png" /></body></html>`. This also shows an error instead of the image.

Is there a way to add an image inline?

**EDIT:**

The second method works on local email, but the receiver's message has an error instead of the actual image.

Comment: Your method 2 is correct, but the proper syntax is `<img src = "[path]/my_plot.png"></img>` not `<img src = "[path]/my_plot.png" />`

Comment: No, the syntax is correct. `<img></img>` = `<img />`

Comment: Oh, you're right. Not sure what the issue is then, I'm able to send images with RDCOMClient that way.

Comment: I found out the problem. The second method works as you said. I was using a path to another machine (server), not my own. So the application was unable to access the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach the image and reference it in the email body using a content id ("cid"):

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
ggsave(tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".png"), p, dpi = 100, width = 5, height = 5)
library(RDCOMClient)
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
attach <- outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(tf)
invisible(attach$PropertyAccessor()$SetProperty(
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E", 
  "image/png"
))
invisible(attach$PropertyAccessor()$SetProperty(
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", 
  cid <- "myggplotimg"
))
outMail[["To"]] = "johndoe@example.com"
outMail[["Subject"]] = "ggplot image"
outMail[["HTMLbody"]] <- sprintf('<p>Here is your image:<br><img src="cid:%s"></p>', cid)
invisible(outMail$Save())
rm(outMail, attach, OutApp)
```

Comment: It's a bit easier actually. You don't have to set the attachment property. If you set the cid in your HTMLBody with the image name (including the extension) it works.

Comment: How would this be done with multiple images embedded in the email? I've been trying to apply this concept to 2 images, but unsuccessful so far.