# Variables in string & ggplots in the body of an outlook email. Is it possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, outlook, r-markdown

I'm hoping to generate an email once my markdown has been completed, with some data and a few ggplots embedded in the body of the email.

I've been able to get it to produce text I want using the code below, however I've been unable to get it to insert the 3 ggplots I need into the body as images (or in any form by that matter) underneath the text I've got.

```
subject_1 <- "Time Update"
subject_2 <- paste0('(', current_time_round,')')

email_body <- paste("<div style='font-family:calibri'><p>Hi</p>
<p>Please see below for the Time update. Data was calculated at", current_time_round,"</p>",
    "<li>", "Specific Vol:", paste0(specific_vol, "%</li>"), "</div>")

date <- as.Date(Sys.time())
email_subject <- paste(subject_1, date, subject_2)

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
Email = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
Email[["to"]] = target
Email[["subject"]] = email_subject

Email[["htmlbody"]] = email_body
Email$Display()
```

The ggplots are stored as objects with the names, "rz", "rs", & "rp". I've tried a number of different methods, including this one: [RDCOMClient (Outlook) - ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067820/rdcomclient-outlook-ggplot)

However that just delivers an error on the images and seems to interfere with the data.
Any advice on how I can get it working would be very appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't able to install / test `RDCOMClient` on R>=4.0, hence `blastula` solution, but this might be helpful : https://www.seancarney.ca/2020/10/10/advanced-email-in-r-embedding-images-and-markdown/

Answer (score 4):

The `blastula` package from RStudio allows to compose mails with [text and plots](https://www.rstudio.com/blog/emails-from-r-blastula-0-3/).

You could create a custom `email.Rmd` file:

````
---
output: blastula::blastula_email 
--- 
Please see below for the time update. 
  
Data was calculated at `r calculationtime`

```{r echo=FALSE}
ggplot(mtcars)+geom_point(aes(x=mpg,y=hp))
```
````

Note that in comparison to standard `RMarkdown`, you can pass the libraries (here `ggplot2`) and the variables (here `calculationtime`) directly in the calling script, see below.

This worked on an Outlook server, after setting up the SMTP credentials :

```
library(blastula) 
library(keyring)
library(ggplot2)

# to be defined beforehand
create_smtp_creds_key(
  id = "test",
  host = "smtp.host.address",
  use_ssl = F,
  port=25,
  overwrite=T
)

# knit mail
calculationtime <- Sys.time()
email <- render_email(input = 'email.Rmd')
# email # uncomment to check body of email in Viewer pane

# send mail
email %>%
  smtp_send(
    from = "test@test.com",
    to = "otheruser@test.com",
    subject = "Time update",
    credentials = creds_key(id = "test")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should also be doable with the `emayili` package with similar syntax, e.g.

```
library(emayili)
calculationtime <- Sys.time()
email <- envelope() %>%
  subject(paste0("Time Update ", Sys.Date(), " ", format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M"))) %>%
  to(target) %>%
  render("email.Rmd")
```

https://datawookie.github.io/emayili/